# C++11 way to check flags

Tags: c++, c++11

The typical C-style approach:

```
#define LOG_ERRORS            1  // 2^0, bit 0
#define LOG_WARNINGS          2  // 2^1, bit 1
#define LOG_NOTICES           4  // 2^2, bit 2
#define LOG_INCOMING          8  // 2^3, bit 3
#define LOG_OUTGOING         16  // 2^4, bit 4
#define LOG_LOOPBACK         32  // and so on...

// Only 6 flags/bits used, so a char is fine
unsigned char flags;

// initialising the flags
flags = LOG_ERRORS;

//initialising to multiple values with OR (|)
flags = LOG_ERRORS | LOG_WARNINGS | LOG_INCOMING;
// sets to 1 + 2 + 8 i.e. bits 0, 1 and 3

// testing for a flag
// AND with the bitmask before testing with ==
if ((flags & LOG_WARNINGS) == LOG_WARNINGS)
   ...

// testing for multiple flags
// as above, OR the bitmasks
if ((flags & (LOG_INCOMING | LOG_OUTGOING))
         == (LOG_INCOMING | LOG_OUTGOING))
   ...
```

Is there a better way in C++11, which keeps the old C style interface (`LOG_INCOMING | LOG_OUTGOING`)? i.e. How can I get rid of the "ugly" way to check which bits are set?

I have been looking at `std::bitset` but this latter only tests for positional queries (i.e. for example it can test if 3rd bit is set) and cannot test for something like this:

```
  LOG_INCOMING | LOG_OUTGOING
```

Comment: The equals is not required in `if ((flags & LOG_WARNINGS) == LOG_WARNINGS)`. `if (flags & LOG_WARNINGS)` is sufficient.

Comment: A bit is still true and false. Use constants with a type if you want to make it c++y.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c/88934#88934)

Comment: What does "C++11eny" mean? And why is your question tagged [tag:c]?

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-bitsets-and-bit-v/184401382

Comment: C++11ny means C++11ny :) i.e. using new features of the language to keep type safety, cleanness etc... 
My question is tagged C because the code I used to explain my question is in C

Comment: Well, you should explain your question in english, maybe with code in the questions programming-language. Just because you give an *additional* example in a second language is no excuse to tag with that (There are few exceptions, when asking about the equivalent to a specific language-feature). Also, the code you posted *is C++*.

Comment: Why is my question down voted jeez. Please explain? It is clear, concise, describes an issue, can be helpful for future SO users...

Comment: @Kam: I agree; an upvote from me.

Comment: @Kam: Is my change good, or did I misinterpret you?

Comment: @Deduplicator, I might have overriden your changed by mistake. Can you please re-edit the post to see what you have done?

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why it's written as `if( (flags & LOG_WARNINGS) == LOG_WARNINGS )` instead of just `if( flags & LOG_WARNINGS )`. Are there any differences I'm not aware of?

Comment: @dyp, DO NOT use the equality operator (i.e. bitflags == bitmask) for testing if a flag is set - that expression will only be true if that flag is set and all others are unset. To test for a single flag you need to use & and == 
http://www.dylanleigh.net/notes/c-cpp-tricks.html

Comment: @Kam I'm not suggesting `if( flags == LOG_WARNINGS )`, I'm suggesting `if( flags & LOG_WARNINGS )`. As far as I can tell, this erases all other bits and tests if the result is nonzero, which should have the same effect as the code you've posted.

Comment: @Kam: The `==` part is redundant, even in C. Non-zero is `true` in conditionals since before `bool` was invented. I don't understand where this myth that you have to write `if ((x & y) == y)` instead of just `if (x & y)` originated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the performance of the code that 0x/1y features will help.  If it's already well tested, you probably want to avoid a re-write (especially if existing code depends on it).

If just want some ideas for how you could use features though, there are some different approaches you could take.

constexpr...

```
constexpr uint8_t bit(const uint8_t n) {
  return 1 << n;
}

constexpr static const uint8_t LOG_ERRORS =   bit(0);
constexpr static const uint8_t LOG_WARNINGS = bit(1);

if (flags & (LOG_ERROR | LOG_WARNINGS))
```

binary literals...

```
static const uint8_t LOG_ERRORS =   0b00000001;
static const uint8_t LOG_WARNINGS = 0b00000010;

if (flags & (LOG_ERRORS | LOG_WARNINGS))
```

variadic templates...

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T bit_or(T t, Ts... ts) {
  return t | bit_or(ts...);
}

template<typename T>
T bit_or(T t) {
  return t;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
bool any_set(T t, Ts... ts) {
  return static_cast<bool>(t & (bit_or(ts...)));
}

constexpr uint8_t bit(const uint8_t n) {
  return 1 << n;
}

constexpr static const uint8_t LOG_ERRORS   = bit(0);
constexpr static const uint8_t LOG_WARNINGS = bit(1);

if (any_set(flags, LOG_ERRORS, LOG_WARNINGS))
```

My personal preference would be to avoid `std::bitset`, since it can't be directly evaluated in a boolean context.  However, I might consider wrapping `flags` in a class, and using an `enum class : uint8_t` for the flags for type safety.  The class would probably be something similar to Java's `EnumSet`.  You could easily overload the bitwise operations (`&`, `|`, `^`, `~`, etc...) for it to preserve the C interface.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace your macros with `static const int`s (well, or an `enum` with explicit values), but other than that your implementation is just fine.

You should not replace good, solid, robust, clear, self-documenting, concise, reliable code with some new template monstrosity just because you can.

Your code is modern enough and this pattern is still very much in use.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Three more C++11 answers for my gold badge. Can't wait!

Comment: So you don't think improving `(flags & LOG_WARNINGS) == LOG_WARNINGS` is worth it?

Comment: @dyp: Well, I'd call it `(flags & LOG_WARNINGS)` and possibly hide it behind an inline function for additional clarity, but really the use of bitsets is so ingrained into our craft that I wouldn't go messing around with it unless there were a problem.

Comment: The problem I have with this statement is that the same could be said about C-style arrays and raw owning pointers (but to a much higher degree). We similarly know about the issues of scoping and type safety that static consts and unscoped enums impose on us; so IMHO there's a consideration to be made *if* the code could become clearer and if so, how much we want to deviate from our old paths to achieve that.

Comment: @dyp: Right, but what I'm saying is that I don't think it can, really. And there's a _lot_ less to gain than with C-style arrays and raw owning pointers. A _lot_.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), which, among other things, allows you to [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set) an N bit to `true`; it also has some methods for conversions to `unsigned` and to `string` ( C++ string, not just a null terminated sequence of `char` C-style )

Other than that, I don't think that there is a more C++-ish way of doing this, but I'll probably keep an approach similar to what Lightness Races in Orbit just described, be conservative and don't add an overhead that you don't *need* .